# how to create index for this query and make it for better performance?

Tags: mysql, indexing

could any one show how to create index for this query and make to a better performance ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` 

FROM `epowergateway`.`error_logs` AS `ErrorLog` 

LEFT JOIN `epowergateway`.`devices` AS `Device` ON (`ErrorLog`.`device_id` =`Device`.`id`)  

WHERE `status` = 'open' AND `type` = 'snmptrap' AND `traptype` = 'LCA' 

AND device_id IN (7, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 11);
```

Comment: You should use count(tbl_name.id) instead of count(*)

Comment: two tables are here ..which table name ? error_logs or devices ?

Comment: You can use `count(error_logs.id)` as `count (*)` is very expensive for mysql

Comment: Please qualify each column name with the table it is in!  We cannot help you without that detail.

Answer (score 0):

device.id should be primary key.

ErrorLog.device_id should be indexed.

assuming both fields should be integer type.

Also as per query I am assuming that most data filteration will be based on device_id, so no need of index on other fields.

Even you can search based on primary key instead of index key as device.id in (7, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 11).

Further share your issue so that can check as per that aspect.

Comment: also i m not seeing any requirement here for left join, you can use simple inner join.

Comment: yes it can also impact, but first make sure device.id and log.device_id fields should be indexed and int type..then check count with various conditions suppose how many rows have both tables and how many rows you are getting by `traptype` = 'LCA' condition only same check with other conditions in where...try to find out which condition will filter most data means fetching less rows...by this we can decide which index will provide performance or we should use merge index but on which fields.

Comment: devices ... has id !
error_logs has device_id , type , status , traptype !
error_logs has 1027655 rows
devices has 10 rows .                                                                                                                 count shows : 0 ,  # Query_time: 1.177578  Lock_time: 0.000263 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 447919

Comment: as per your comment you are passing almost all device id in query (as there are 10 rows in device table and you are passing all in query) means there is no data filteration based on this...your explain is showing that query is scanning approx. 4.5 lacs records even count is 0. this can be also a reaon as query is not getting any row so can take time... you need to check where you are getting some count then what is count value and how many rows are scanned by query...and which condition is doing data filteration...which will help to get actual problem.

Comment: that's a brilliant answer . Thanks i ' ll try it .

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(status, type, traptype, device_id)
```

*If* those are in the same table.

Beware: `COUNT(*)` with a `JOIN` is likely to give you an inflated answer.